# Is there a way in typescript to ensure a function passed to a higher order one has a specific return type?

Tags: typescript

A function expects another generic function as input and it's defined as:

```
function higherOrderFunction(fn: Function): Function<void> {
  return (...args: any[]) => fn(...args);
}
```

called as

```
function fun(x: number, y: string) { console.log(`${x}${+y}`); }

const higherOrderFunctionWithFunction = higherOrderFunction(fun);
higherOrderFunctionWithFunction(1, '3')
```

This throws

> ts(2315): Function is not a generic

which makes sense. Therefore, **how do I enforce that the function returned by `higherOrderFunction` has a specific return type (whether `void` or another type) ? (no matter if we specify the return type in `fun` "lower order" function)**

I am aware typescript has `ReturnType` utility function. However, how to use that in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can make `higherOrderFunction` to be a generic with type is return type of parameter function.

In general, a function will be like `(...args: any[]) => T` , `T` is return type.

The first, create a alias type for function type, then use the type for parameter and return type of `higherOrderFunction`:

```
type FunctionType<T> = (...args: any[]) => T;

function higherOrderFunction<T>(fn: FunctionType<T>): FunctionType<T> {
  return (...args: any[]) => fn(...args);
}
```

Usage,

```
function fun(x: number, y: string) {
  console.log(`${x}${+y}`);
}

const higherOrderFunctionWithFunction = higherOrderFunction(fun);
const result = higherOrderFunctionWithFunction(1, '3'); // return "void"
```

```
function fun(x: number, y: string) {
  return `${x}${+y}`;
}

const higherOrderFunctionWithFunction = higherOrderFunction(fun);
const result = higherOrderFunctionWithFunction(1, '3'); // return string
```

Comment: how does this enforce a specific return type for `fun`? Let's say I want the function to return `void` and not `string`? (therefore having a compiler error in your 2nd example)